# Class 1 not being classified, what could be wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tflite

I am using deep learning for a project and after training a model, I used `X_test & y_test` to validate the model and my accuracy was over 99%. However, when I used TFLite to compress the model and then used Interpreter for inferencing, the output of my confusion matrix and the classification report was suprising to me as only the "0" class was classified while the "1" was  not classified. Please, could someone help me on what I need to do to be able to classify the 2 classes (0 & 1). here's the code I used

```
data.head(5)
         V1        V2          V3         V4     Labels
0   -0.253908   0.088630    0.247481    -0.358719   0
1   -0.153446   0.676119    0.390619    -0.303980   0
2   -0.153728   0.676059    0.390683    -0.303741   0
3   -0.146797   0.670025    0.405856    -0.302517   0
4   -0.253907   0.088625    0.247481    -0.358713   0

data.Labels.value_counts()

Out[] 1    128025
      0     97686
      Name: Labels, dtype: int64

y = data[['Labels']]
X = data.drop(['Labels'], axis=1)

y.shape, X.shape

Out[] ((225711, 1), (225711, 4))

# spliting the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape

Out[] ((151226, 4), (151226, 1), (74485, 4), (74485, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(4,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=300)

model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

       2328/2328 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0125 - accuracy: 0.9971
Out[] [0.01249629631638527, 0.9971001148223877]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(r"C:\Users\44759\df3")
tflite_model = converter.convert()

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(r"C:\Users\44759\df3")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()

q_aware_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

      2328/2328 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0133 - accuracy: 0.9968
Out[] [0.013261106796562672, 0.9967510104179382]

#Check Input Tensor Shape
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path = "tflite_qaware_model.tflite")
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print("Input Shape:", input_details[0]['shape'])
print("Input Type:", input_details[0]['dtype'])
print("Output Shape:", output_details[0]['shape'])
print("Output Type:", output_details[0]['dtype'])

Input Shape: [1 4]
Input Type: <class 'numpy.float32'>
Output Shape: [1 1]
Output Type: <class 'numpy.float32'>

#Resize Tensor Shape
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], (74485, 4))
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(output_details[0]['index'], (74485, 1))
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print("Input Shape:", input_details[0]['shape'])
print("Input Type:", input_details[0]['dtype'])
print("Output Shape:", output_details[0]['shape'])
print("Output Type:", output_details[0]['dtype'])

Input Shape: [74485     4]
Input Type: <class 'numpy.float32'>
Output Shape: [74485     1]
Output Type: <class 'numpy.float32'>

X_test_numpy = np.array(X_test, dtype=np.float32)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], X_test_numpy)
interpreter.invoke()
tflite_model_predictions = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print("Prediction results shape:", tflite_model_predictions.shape)
prediction_classes = np.argmax(tflite_model_predictions, axis=1)

Prediction results shape: (74485, 1)

confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction_classes)
print(confusion_mat)

[[32302     0]
 [42183     0]]

print(classification_report(prediction_classes, y_test))

               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.43      0.60     74485
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

    accuracy                           0.43     74485
   macro avg       0.50      0.22      0.30     74485
weighted avg       1.00      0.43      0.60     74485
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. The issue of only the "0" label class being classified was coming from this line `prediction_classes = np.argmax(tflite_model_predictions, axis=1)`. Obviously, the `argmax()` function was returning the index of the maximum value which was not what I wanted. Obviously, when I printed`tflite_model_predictions`, the values were `0., 0.99945, 0.99945, 0.99945, 0., 0.99945, ...`. Therefore, I had to ignore the line `prediction_classes = np.argmax(tflite_model_predictions, axis=1)` and use

```
p = np.where(tflite_model_predictions)>0.5,1,0
confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(p, y_test)
print(confusion_mat)
```